# IIS setup with Vuejs and Laravel

Tags: laravel, azure, vue.js, iis, web-config

In my Laravel + Vuejs project I have the following structure:

- wwwroot/dist folder where the client application is located in /wwwroot/dist.
- wwwroot/public folder, entry point of Laravel

The client application consumes a Laravel REST API. There are also other APIs for different utilities.
I have the following web.config file in /wwwroot. The idea is that all requests go to /dist to access the client app, except those coming from the api|src|flyer|admon|user subdomains. This is my web.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="/public/index.php" />
            <add value="/dist/index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="specific routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*(api|src|flyer|admon|user)\.mysite\.com.*" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/public/index.php" appendQueryString="True" />
         </rule>
         <rule name="general routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/dist/" appendQueryString="True"/>
         </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

All requests that work with the first rule (api|src|flyer|admon|user subdomains) work correctly. The issue is that my client app doesn't work, it seems like it doesn't process Javascript files. Note that in the content of the JS files it shows that of index.html:

[image]

The problem is not in my Vuejs application, because I have it installed on another Apache/Linux machine and everything works correctly with the same deployment structure.

**EDIT**

This is my virtual path config in Azure, where my web.config is placed:
[image]

Comment: Are there any error messages? I think you need to open the network panel to see the request information in detail.

Comment: Yes, I have an error in the console 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'. I think it is because as I explained, the content of all the static files that it serves really corresponds to the index.html file and not to the corresponding css/js

Comment: In addition, after the jquery file imported in index.html is packaged and deployed to the server, Uncaught SyntaxError: `Unexpected token '<'` error will also occur.